# How to make the sound from Will.I.Am - Scream and Shout

Tags: sound-design

How do I make the sounds from

from 0 to 13 seconds.

More specifically the ambiant voice like sounds, the percussion and also the kind of filter sweep going on.

Answer (score 2):

The voice is produced by using reverb-freeze, or reverb on a short vocal extract with full sustain. This is then fed to a channel which is gradually faded in.

The filter is first a high-pass filter gradually increasing the threshold, then cross-fades fast into the same sound but on a low-pass filter. Or as this is highly likely using automation channels the filter cut-off type is just switched and the threshold value set to almost bottom again.